# Java: Overloading constructors which call each other

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

Consider a class which is instanciated from a data found in a CSV line, and stores some of its fields. It makes sense to create two constructors for this class -one from the raw CSV line, and one with explicit variable assignment.

e.g.,

```java
public MyClass(String csvLine)
{
    String[] fields = StringUtils.split(csvLine, ',');
    this(fields[3], fields[15], Integer.parseInt([fields[8]));
}

public MyClass(String name, String address, Integer age)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
    this.age=age;
}
```

In Java, this fails because:

> Constructor call must be the first statement in a
>   constructor   WhereOnEarth.java

What's the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not mix the class that represents the parsed content and the content parsing class. I would create a MayClassFactory or something along those lines:

```
public class MyClassFactory {

    public MyClass fromCsvLine(String csvLine) {
        String[] fields = StringUtils.split(csvLine, ',');
        return new MyClass(fields[3], fields[15], Integer.parseInt([fields[8]));
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: +1 This could also be a static factory method in `MyClass`, e.g. `MyClass.parse(String csv)` (if you don't mind a _little_ mixing!)

Comment: @DNA: yep, see my answer. Although if parsing is a little bit more complex (or there is more than one source, e.g. XML), decoupling is highly encouraged.

Comment: I only use static for util classes, like StringUtils and so on. When writing a factory, I would design for inheritance and therefore don't use static if possible. However, you could make this a static inner class if you like.

Comment: Why is it an instance method?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: I support non-static method. `MyClassFactory` might be stateful, e.g. holding CSV parsing configuration/validation rules.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline like I said, to support inheritance. Someone could extend it or write a MyClassMockFactory that only creates Mock objects for testing purpose. Static methods can not be overwritten.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my take:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static MyClass fromCsvLine(String csvLine) {
        String[] fields = StringUtils.split(csvLine, ',');
        return new MyClass(fields[3], fields[15], Integer.parseInt([fields[8]));
    }

    //...

}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass my = MyClass.fromCsvLine("...");
```

Comment: Probably `MyClass` shouldn't "know" about CSV files, so putting in a different class (along with `toCSVLine` may make more sense). But certainly static creation method is the way to go - constructor are a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 5):

Create a method

```
private init(String name, String address, Integer age) {}
```

Call it from both constructors.

Comment: Only problem is that this makes it impossible to use final variables. No nice way around that but using a static initializer - well you can solve it with constructors and no code duplication, but obviously that gets ugly..

Comment: I prefer this method (pun!?) since it facilitates testing.